# solaris 10 (sparc64) ramdisk (like shmfs or tmpfs)

Tags: memory, solaris, mmap, ramdisk

There is an ramdisk capability in Linux, which is achieved with mounting shmfs of tmpfs, like:

```
# mount -t shm shmfs -o size=20g /dev/shm
```

or

```
# mount –t tmpfs tmpfs /dev/shm
```

Also, some linuxes have `ramfs`, which is "ramfs is similar to shmfs, except that pages are not pageable or swappable"

```
# mount -t ramfs ramfs /dev/shm
```

I want to create ramdisk on solaris 10 (sparc64) with big size (tens of GB). How can I do this in solaris?
How can I create not just a ramdisk in solaris, but nonswappable ramdisk?

Then I want to use big file from ramdisk to mmap memory into 32-bit process, so the solution should allow me to mmap small parts of files from ramdisk into 32bit application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a virtual memory based disk:

```
# mount -F tmpfs -o size=20000m swap /mountpoint
```

For a physical memory one:

```
# a=$(ramdiskadm -a bigdisk 20g)
# newfs $a
# mount $a /mountpoint
```

By the way, Solaris (more precisely SunOS) was the first Unix to implement tmpfs around 1987.

Comment: Thanks! Is there option to disallow swapping of tmpfs/ramdisk?

Comment: ramdisks are never swapped out by design, tmpfs is always swappable by design.